# what is the python(2.5.2)'s logging mechanism? is there log4j look a like library or standard class of python/geodjango will do?

Tags: python, logging, geodjango

I am planning to add logging mechanism in my python&geodjango web service.
Is there log4j look a like logging mechanism in python/geodjango?

I am looking for log4j's dailyrollingfileappender equivalent. Then automatically delete all 1month old log files.

Any guidance is appreciated.

**UPDATES1**
I am thinking of the below format.

```
datetime(ms)|log level|current thread name|client ip address|logged username|source file|source file line number|log message
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - Python 2.5 includes the 'logging' module. One of the handlers it supports is `handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler`, this is what you're looking for. 'logging' is very easy to use:

example:

```
import logging
import logging.config

logging.fileConfig('mylog.conf')
logger = logging.getLogger('root')
```

The following is your config file for logging

```
#======================

# mylog.conf
[loggers]
keys=root

[handlers]
keys=default

[formatters]
keys=default

[logger_root]
level=INFO
handlers=default
qualname=(root) # note - this is used in non-root loggers
propagate=1 # note - this is used in non-root loggers
channel=
parent=

[handler_default]
class=handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler
level=INFO
formatter=default
args=('try.log', 'd', 1)

[formatter_default]
format=%(asctime)s %(pathname)s(%(lineno)d): %(levelname)s %(message)s
```

Comment: `import logging...logger = logging.getLogger('root')` are need to include every py files to use the logging system?

Comment: where do i need to put mylog.conf? is the filename could be changed? like mylog.py?

Comment: `args=('try.log', 'd', 1)` -> 1 is backupCount? 1 means one file (plus current log file try.log) will be remained?

Comment: Third line of your example is missing 'config'. It should be logging.config.fileConfig('log.conf')